# SVG vector image not showing on HTML element

Tags: html, css, electron

I am trying to create an icon button, everything works, except from the SVG image. When I add the SVG file as the `background-image` using CSS it doesn't seem to appear. I even tried using the `::before` pseudo-element (or class, am not sure which one it is). All the methods I have tried were all suggested by people on StackOverflow but I don't seem to understand why my own case is different. When I try to duplicate the code I find in the answers on StackOverflow, it works, but mine doesn't seem to work. Please, what am I doing wrong. I am new to CSS, HTML and Javascript.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Untitled - NoteBook</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/titlebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/editorStyle.css">
</head>
<script src="../UI/renderer.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="titlebar-container">
            <div id="titlebar">
                <div id="drag-region">
                    <p id="window-title">Notebook</p>
                </div>
                <div id="window-icon-container">
                    <button class="icon" id="minimize">
                    </button>
                    <button class="icon" id="maximize"></button>
                    <button class="icon" id="close">
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div id="menubar"></div> -->
        </div>
        <div id="split-container">
            <div id="note-list" class="split">
                <ul>
                    <li>Note #1</li>
                    <li>Note #2</li>
                    <li>Note #3</li>
                    <li>Note #4</li>
                    <li>Note #5</li>
                    <li>Note #6</li>
                    <li>Note #7</li>
                    <li>Note #8</li>
                    <li>Note #9</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <textarea id="text" class="split"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS

```
* {
    --transparent: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    --medium-opacity: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
}

#menubar {
    background-color: rgb(76, 25, 124);
}

#titlebar-container {
    top: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 30px;
    
}

#titlebar {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
    background-color: rgb(76, 25, 124);
    user-select: none;
}

#drag-region {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

#window-title {
    font: menu;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:  rgb(226, 214, 236);
    height: 10px;
    background-color: var(--transparent);
    margin: 5px;
    z-index: 5000;
}

#window-icon-container {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3000;
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
    height: 32px;
    width: 138px;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: var(--transparent);
}

.icon {
    width: 46px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--transparent);
    /* cursor: pointer; */
}

#close:before {
    content: url(/Icons/close.svg);
}

#minimize:hover {
    background-color: var(--medium-opacity);
}

#maximize:hover {
    background-color: var(--medium-opacity);
}

#close:hover {
    background-color: rgb(173, 30, 25)
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: and 

`element {
  background-image: url(/images/image.svg);
}` 

doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, background-image doesn't work

Comment: Your script should either be inside `<head>` or `<body>`, not in between.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give it a width height and position it.

```css
.close::before {
  content:url('https://oxoinnovation.com/images/facebook-f.svg');
  width:50px;height:50px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<button class="close"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. My Javascript skills aren't so good, so I didn't know my problem was in the file path to the SVG image, the file path was wrong. So I changed the file path and this time, I used the `background-image` property instead. Even when I changed the file path, when I edited the SVG image and saved it into that former location, the SVG image disappeared again, so I deleted the SVG image and moved a copy of the SVG into the correct location, and it appeared once more